# Most Accurate and correct way to compare two large windows 8.1 registry files (C++/C# or any anything else)

Tags: c#, c++, windows, registry

I exported the entire registry of my computer and it's size is around 350 MB. After that I installed some things and exported the registry again. The file size now is around 351 MB. I want to know the difference in two files i.e. what registry keys were added. One way I can think of doing is that - write a c++ program that loads the first file in memory and stores the lines in an unordered_map. Then I read line by line - the second file and see whether each line exists in the first file or not? Now writing this code is easy. But I don't know the structure of registry files. So whether some key-value pairs could be stored in multiple lines or all are stored in single lines. I am sure someone would have encountered this problem before. Any ideas will be great. Thanks. I know that C# also has a class to read registry files. I will look at that as well.

VVV

Comment: How do you define "best"? Fastest? Least memory?

Comment: Sorry - my mistake - I didn't make it clear - I want anything that will give me correct answer - it doesn't matter how long the process takes. But I want EACH AND EVERY REGISTRY KEY that was added after the installation. I have updated the question.

Comment: Have you tried using command line tools like `fc` or `comp` ?

Comment: The correct way to do it in the first place is to use something like [RegMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896652.aspx). You have it monitor the installation you're about to run, and it tracks all of the accesses to the registry as they happen, so that after the installation you know everything that was done to it. There's no comparison to be done afterward.

Comment: @John - yes it just hangs my computer :-)

Comment: @Ken - Oh okay but then I will need to uninstall it and then re-install it. Even if I am monitoring and suppose there are 50 entries that changed/got added then how can I remember all of those? Or will it be outputed to a file? Thanks.

Comment: Regmon tracks them, and you can do several things with the output. It's free, and has documentation that's pretty complete. Download it and check the help file for capabilities. (It's easier than trying to compare two copies of the registry yourself, especially when one is binary and the other is text.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you export it with regedit into a .reg file?
If yes, comparing is simple. The .reg files are just text files, so you can use any diff utility.

This should be accurate, if the diff utility can handle files that big.

Comment: Problem is that diff utility I used are commands like fc, comp or softwares like notepad++, winmerge, differmge etc. but they all hang my computer. And even if it becomes responsive, it hangs again when I use the scrollbar.